# Generic method is not type-sensitive

Tags: java, generics

I am learning the Generics and tried to alter one of the examples. I expected the code will not compile even with the different types passed into the generic method `arraysEqual()`. Turned out it complies and runs.
**Why `<T>` type is not limiting input parameters to be the same (in this case Integer and String arrays)?**

```
public class GenericMethodDemo {

    static <T> boolean arraysEqual (T x[], T y[]){
        if (x.length != y.length) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            if (!x[i].equals(y[i])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5}, 
        nums2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String svals[] = {"1", "2","3","4","5"};

        if (arraysEqual(nums, nums2)) System.out.println("nums is equal nums2");
        if (!arraysEqual(nums, svals)) System.out.println("nums is not equal svals");
    }
}
```

output is:

```
nums is equal nums2
nums is not equal svals
```

Comment: Because `Integer` and `String` are both `Object` types. You need to give `T` some kind of more specific bounds. It's compile time type checking only. After type erasure it's always `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays and generics do not work well together. Also, arrays have a broken type system. That broken type system part, that explains why your code compiles here.

To explain what's broken about it, and why that then results in your code working, first, some background info is required.

### Variance

In java, the types themselves are **covariant**. This means *Whenever something of type A is required, anything of a **subtype** of A is also okay*.

This works fine:

```
Object o = "hello";
```

Because "hello" is a string, and String is a subtype of Object, therefore this is okay.

But generics are **invariant**: *Whenever something of type A is required, only *A* will do*.

Let's try the same construct in generics:

```
List<Object> o = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This is a **compiler error**: thus showing that generics start off invariant.

But, generics are interesting in that you can choose your variance. For example, if you want covariance, you can ask for this:

```
List<? extends Object> o = new ArrayList<String>();
```

That *does* compile: You now have a List of 'covariant Object'.

The reason that generics are invariant by default is because math / life / the universe. It is the correct way to do it. After all, imagine that generics were covariant like the basic types were, then you could write:

```
List<String> stringsOnly = new Arraylist<String>();
List<Object> objects = stringsOnly;
objects.add(5);
String string = stringsOnly.get(0); // but this is '5', a number!
```

The above code fortunately does not compile, because the second line won't, because generics are invariant. Opt into covariance and it still does not compile:

```
List<String> stringsOnly = new Arraylist<String>();
List<?> objects = stringsOnly;
objects.add(5);
String string = stringsOnly.get(0); // but this is '5', a number!
```

This time, the third line won't compile. You can't add anything to a List of covariant anything (well, except the literal `null`).

Arrays, unfortunately, breaks all this. Let's do the first snippet in array form:

```
String[] stringsOnly = new String[1];
Object[] objects = stringsOnly;
objects[0] = 5;
String string = stringsOnly[0];
```

This actually compiles. However, if you run it, you get an ArrayStoreException on the third line.

The reason your code does work, is:

`T` is bound to be Object. Which works: String[] and Integer[] are both valid, in that `Object[] x = new String[10];` is valid java. This is mathematically unsound, as this last snippet showed, but java thinks it is okay.

As your arraysEqual method only reads, and never writes anything, you don't run into the ArrayStoreException.

I strongly recommend you actually write these snippets and experiment; variance is a hard concept, but fundamental to programming.

### Arrays in java

Arrays are low level constructs, especially arrays of non-primitive types. You should not use them unless you have a performance reason (and you rarely should).

- They have broken variance.
- They will never be fixed (because there are better alternatives, and their problems are sometimes used by code that has performance requirements, so these problems cannot be fixed without breaking old code, and for the past 25 years, java has been highly resistant to making changes that break old code, and there are no indications this is going to change anytime soon).
- They have broken hash and equals and toString implementations.
- They cannot be coerced into having a read-only view or being immutable.
- They cannot grow or shrink.

Use `List<T>` instead which suffers from none of these problems.